# How can I resolve a "NameError: name 'null' is not defined" error while trying to import any module in Python 2.7

Tags: python, python-2.7

I installed python today and used pip install successfully to get some modules. But I am unable to import any .py modules.

I created mod.py (it has a simple print command) in the same directory as the code I am trying to run. I uninstalled and reinstalled anaconda as well. But the error persists.
Anyone with any ideas on how to fix this?
Thanks!

```
import mod

NameErrorTraceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-1-18de99490651> in <module>()
----> 1 import mod

C:\Users\Mayank\mod.py in <module>()
      3   {
      4    "cell_type": "code",
----> 5    "execution_count": null,
      6    "metadata": {},
      7    "outputs": [],

NameError: name 'null' is not defined
```

This is a sample of what the .py code looks like in the editor (same problem):

```
{
 "cells": [
  {
   "cell_type": "code",
   "execution_count": null,
   "metadata": {},
   "outputs": [],
   "source": [
    "def fib(n):    # write Fibonacci series up to n\n",
    "    a, b = 0, 1\n",
    "    while b < n:\n",
    "        print b,\n",
    "        a, b = b, a+b\n",
    "\n",
    "def fib2(n):   # return Fibonacci series up to n\n",
    "    result = []\n",
    "    a, b = 0, 1\n",
    "    while b < n:\n",
    "        result.append(b)\n",
    "        a, b = b, a+b\n",
    "    return result"
   ]
  }
 ],
 "metadata": {
  "kernelspec": {
   "display_name": "Python 2",
   "language": "python",
   "name": "python2"
  },
  "language_info": {
   "codemirror_mode": {
    "name": "ipython",
    "version": 2
   },
   "file_extension": ".py",
   "mimetype": "text/x-python",
   "name": "python",
   "nbconvert_exporter": "python",
   "pygments_lexer": "ipython2",
   "version": "2.7.15"
  }
 },
 "nbformat": 4,
 "nbformat_minor": 2
}
```

Comment: This occurs if you create a Notebook and then rename it to a PY file. If you open that file, the source Python code will wrapped with curly braces, double quotes, with the first several lines containing the erroneous `null` reference. You can actually import this as-is, but you have to stop and restart the kernel for the notebook doing the `import` statements FIRST. Best to clean up that code back to pure Python, and better still to just create a blank PY file and drop your cell code in directly instead of renaming the IPYNB files.

Answer (score 21):

`null` isn't a reserved word like it is in JavaScript. `None` is used.

Comment: Nathan - thanks. But I dont follow (beginner here). Could you please expand on your idea?

Comment: Yeah. Somewhere in your code you're referencing `null` which you haven't defined and isn't defined by Python, so you get a name error aka this variable doesn't exist error

Comment: For reference, mod.py is very basic:


import time
def foo():
    print time.time()

Answer (score 8):

I figured out the issue. I was doing 'Save As' mod.py for the code I was writing. Instead, I needed to 'Save As 'mod' and then 'Download As' .py file type. This was only an issue due to the way the module file is saved/created in Jupyter. The responses to my question yesterday were helpful in me to figure this out. Thanks, everyone!

Answer (score 4):

`null` is not pre-defined in Python. You may have gotten it by copying and pasting a JSON object. Use `None` in place of `null` to denote null objects.

Comment: Hi - thanks for the response (this is a really great community) but  I have no idea where the null is coming from actually. The code for mod.py is basically just a simple print command. What is a JSON object? Thanks again.

Answer (score 2):

That is code from a Jupyter notebook, which is stored in JSON format and cannot be run directly by Python. To fix it, remove everything that doesn't correspond to the `'source'` attribute.

Comment: Hi - thanks for the response. As a beginner I am not sure I follow. I am not sure what the source attribute isn’t or how I would remove it. Is it possible for you to expand on your you suggestion please? Thanks again.

Comment: Open `mod.py`, ctrl-F "source" and copy everything after the `:"` to the next `"`.

Comment: I am trying this on my home computer and its the same problem. I have another random .py file fibo.py and I posted the code for it above. I was confused about what I am supposed to move after "source" and to where. Apologies for the continuing questions!

Comment: I tried importing on spyder and it seems to be working. So this appears tied to Jupyter somehow? What am I doing wrong I wonder?

Answer (score 2):

I think the problem was that your original saved file was not in python format. I was having the same problem as when I saved from Jupytr. The file had an extension
.ipynb which is a python notebook format.

To convert the .ipynb to a .py (which is a text file) I ran the following command in the terminal window:

```
 $ jupyter nbconvert --to script mynotebook.ipynb
```

This created a file "mynotebook.py" which I could then run using

```
$ python mynotebook.py
```

in the terminal window.

Comment: Thanks a lot for this Answer. It helped make my day not suck

Comment: How to do that conversion in colab?

Answer (score 2):

I had this issue just remaining the ipynb file to .py. What worked for me is to just copy the script from the ipynb file to a new empty .py file.

Comment: This does not really answer the question. If you have a different question, you can ask it by clicking [Ask Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask). To get notified when this question gets new answers, you can [follow this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/345661). Once you have enough [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation), you can also [add a bounty](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) to draw more attention to this question. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/30223823)

Comment: How to do that in colab?

Answer (score 0):

I fixed this by running every cell at least one time, so    "execution_count": is changed to 1. Then save .py file.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same error when I received a request data and used 'print(json.dumps(data, indent=1))'. I was able to fix it by using 'pprint(data)' instead.

Answer (score 0):

None is used to indicate the absence of data, None is considered a value, and while None indicates the absence of data, None is different from a value of type str, int or float.

The type None is, in many cases, "null" or "empty" can be used as a value, but there is no official "null" type in Python.

Answer (score 0):

Better try this :
go to the directory where the module file should be present and create a text file with name mod.py

/users/abc/python/mod.py

now open this file using jupyter doc explorer :
http://localhost:8888/tree/python/mod.py

and now add your code. for example :

mod.py (file content as below) :

def sum1(x,y):
z=x+y
return z

Answer (score -2):

Just define the null on the top of your code like

```
null = ""
```

and after this, the null will be replaced by the empty string ("") in your data.
Thanks.

Comment: An empty string and `None` are not the same.

Comment: And mixing in non-Python syntax is a surefire way to get your codebase into a mess. Now you have two different things that are intended to both be one thing.

Comment: Python uses the None in place of null, so you can define like this,
null = None

Comment: Again, you *could*, but you *shouldn't*.