# How to use "jupyter-run" to call a jupyter notebook on local?

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, jupyter, jupyter-lab

I'm trying to call a jupyter notebook Untitled.ipynb from anaconda prompt using
jupyter-run Untitled.ipynb
and I get the error message "NameError: name 'null' is not defined. How can I fix this?

Comment: Can you provide the exact command you're trying to run, as well as perhaps the file structure?

Comment: Have a look at the answers [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55426505/how-can-i-resolve-a-nameerror-name-null-is-not-defined-error-while-trying-t).

Comment: @joe-fivefifty The exact command is "jupyter-run Untitled.ipynb" and the notebook contains only one line "print('hello')".

Comment: Thank you @funie200; the answers you've mentioned are really helpful if I want to convert my .ipynb to .py: running "jupyter-run Untitled.py" from anaconda prompt is working properly. The problem is that according to Jupyter Runner docs (please see https://pythonhosted.org/jupyter_runner/), "Jupyter runners allows to run multiple notebooks over multiple sets of parameters" and  their example of how to use is "jupyter-run notebook.ipynb". This is exactly the code I'm trying to use and it's not working (see error above).

Answer (score 1):

`jupyter-run` is a command to run *scripts* in a jupyter kernel:

```
jupyter run script.py
curl https://example.com/some_r_script.R | jupyter run --kernel=ir
```

To execute a *notebook*, you can use

```
jupyter nbconvert --execute notebook.ipynb
```