# How to run multiple notebooks in Google Colab

Tags: python, google-colaboratory

I have several different Notebooks in Google Colab that I use to automate some tasks. I want to create a single Notebook that runs all this tasks, so I can open a single tab with one single Notebook, run it and it will run all other tasks inside these different Notebooks.

I have two questions regarding this problem:

1. The solution I found is not working (I will describe it below). How
   do I make it work?
2. Is there a better solution than the one I found?

About the first question:

Image I have Notebook_1 and Notebook_2 each one with a bunch of functions that automate my tasks. What I am doing is, downloading them as Notebook_1.py and Notebook_2.py, saving these files in a Google Drive folder. Then in my Notebook_main, which is the notebook that should house all notebooks, I run:

```
# Mounts Google Drive
from google.colab import drive
drive.mount('/content/drive')

# Copies .py files into Google Colab
!cp /content/drive/MyDrive/my_modules/Notebook_1.py /content
!cp /content/drive/MyDrive/my_modules/Notebook_2.py /content

# Import Modules

import Notebook_1
import Notebook_2
```

If I want to run a simple function inside these modules I just do:

```
Notebook_1.run_simple_function()
```

and this works. My problem happens when the function I am trying to run from the Notebook_1, for example, uses another module. Then I get the following error:

```
name 'os' is not defined
```

I imagine it happens because inside Notebook_1.py I call:

```
import os
...
os.remove(os.path.join(dir_download, item))
...
```

And I also think this will happen with all the modules that I call inside Notebook_1.py.

I have tried importing theses modules in Notebook_main, but it did not work. I do not know how to fix this. I need help.

Another issue is that I use a lot of Selenium, which needs to be installed in Google Colab before being imported. So I need to install and import it in `Notebook_main` and when I run a function with `Notebook_1.run_function_that_uses_selenium()` it should use the import from `Notebook_main`.

The second question is simpler. I just want to know if there is a better way to achieve the same result, i.e. run different Notebooks in Google Colab from a single notebook.

My constriction is that I can only use Google Colab and other Google related Platforms, I can not run anything locally.

Comment: Have you tried the approach described in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59169452/9987623) answer?

Comment: No. The only approach I have tried is the one I have described. I will try your suggestion, though. I still would like to know what I am doing wrong and why my solution is not working.

Comment: You may need to provide an [MRE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) for the `NameError`.  I can easily call a function that uses something out of the standard library and that is saved in a module from a notebook, as you are trying to do.

Comment: For using something like Selenium, I would recommend keeping everything in notebook format, installing and importing packages in notebooks that use those packages (in your case, installing and importing Selenium in Notebook_1.ipynb), and using `%run /content/drive/MyDrive/my_notebooks/Notebook_1.ipynb` in your main notebook, which both runs the installation command and imports the functions into main notebook so you can call them there.

Comment: I know this is is a stupid question, but my directory and file name has spaces. What should I do? root:File `'/content/drive/MyDrive/Colab Notebooks/Baixar relatórios.py'` not found.

Comment: You need to escape those spaces by placing a backslash before the space in the path, e.g., `/content/drive/MyDrive/Colab\ Notebooks/Baixar\ relatórios.py`

Comment: %run /content/drive/MyDrive/Colab\ Notebooks/Baixar\ relatórios\ FBads gives me this error: NameError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
/content/drive/MyDrive/Colab Notebooks/Baixar relatórios FBads in <module>()
----> 1 {"nbformat":4,"nbformat_minor":0,"metadata":{"colab":{"name":"Baixar relatórios FBads","provenance":[{"file_id":"1aIoHejsWIurmz5ox__uJIOJu1WS7SBkN","timestamp":1652973400332},{"file_id":"1-9lR1Na16D9hM-dponQi44NBSZJaP5F5","timestamp":1637328344750}],"collapsed_sections":[]},"kernelspec":{"name":"pyth...
NameError: name 'null' is not defined

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55426505/how-can-i-resolve-a-nameerror-name-null-is-not-defined-error-while-trying-t#comment105140585_55426505. At this point, I don't know if you are trying to run a notebook or a .py file, but if it's a .py file you are creating from a notebook, the best thing to do is to create it by going to File > Download > Download .py in Google Colab.

Comment: I simply clicked on "copy path" on the file and pasted after %run. I comes without a .extension. I have tried bouth .py and .ipynb. It does not work either way.

Comment: There is something off about how you created your file.  A file should have a file extension. I can't add anything more beyond what I said above.

Answer (score 2):

Simple.

```
from google.colab import drive
drive.mount('/content/gdrive')
```

then

```
libdir = "/content/gdrive/My\ Drive/Colab\ Notebooks/lib/"
%run {libdir}MyNotebook.ipynb
```