# error in actions.py file by rasa, "execution_count": null,

Tags: python-3.x, yaml, rasa, rasa-core

if any one could help as im running a code to call actions.py file, while always return to me with an error "line 46, in  "execution_count": null, NameError: name 'null' is not defined" although no word 'null' in my actions.py file code as follow;

```
from typing import Any, Text, Dict, List
from sklearn.ensemble import RandomForestRegressor
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
from rasa_sdk import Action, Tracker
from rasa_sdk.executor import CollectingDispatcher
import pandas as pd

class Action_Train_Model(Action):
    def name(self) -> Text:
        return "action_train_model"

    def run(self, dispatcher: CollectingDispatcher, tracker: Tracker, domain: Dict[Text, Any]) -> List[Dict[Text, Any]]:

        df = pd.read_excel('C:/Users/ahmed.gabr/myenv/Tetuan City power consumption.xlsx')

        X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(df[['Temp', 'Wind Speed']], df['Power consumption'], test_size=0.2, random_state=42)

        rf = RandomForestRegressor(n_estimators=100, random_state=42)
        rf.fit(X_train, y_train)

        tracker.slots["model"] = rf

        dispatcher.utter_message(text="Model trained successfully.")

        return []

class Action_Test_Model(Action):
    def name(self) -> Text:
        return "action_test_model"

    def run(self, dispatcher: CollectingDispatcher, tracker: Tracker, domain: Dict[Text, Any]) -> List[Dict[Text, Any]]:

        rf = tracker.get_slot("model")

        test_data = pd.read_excel('C:/Users/ahmed.gabr/myenv/Tetuan City power consumption.xlsx')

        predictions = rf.predict(test_data[['Temp', 'Wind Speed']])
        response = "Predictions: {}".format(predictions)
        dispatcher.utter_message(text=response)

        return []
```

i tried 1- ensuring the file loacations 2- save the python file to actions.ipynp, then download as.py file 3- run each section from the code by jupyter notebook to avoid any errors 4- match the actions in the actions.py file with the actions listed in my domain.yml file in the model directory 5- ensure that the actions file in the same project directory

i expected when run command 'rasa run actions' to run the file with no errors to continue the communcating with my bot

Comment: If you can pls format your outputs and the codes to help better understand the issue.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

As I read from your description this seems like an issue resulting from you creating a jupyter notebook and then renaming it to a .py file. In this process some of the original contents of the .ipynp file are safed to the .py file.

The solution could be to CREATE a new `actions.py` file and copy all of the above code into it.

As mentioned in the first comment [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55426505/how-can-i-resolve-a-nameerror-name-null-is-not-defined-error-while-trying-t)